# SQL Server Linked Server with different active directory domain credentials

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a remote database I need to create a linked server to. The problem is it's been set up with my group's functional account an not my own. The only way I can think of doing this is logging out of my personal work account and then back in with out functional account and then set up the link that way, but that is impractical.

So my question is, is there any possible way to set up a linked server using different active directory credentials on a SQL Server 2005 server?\

EDIT: Bascially I am logged in as AD_MAIN\OhioDude but I need to authenticate to the remote server using AD_MAIM\DeptGroup

Comment: Please use the term "SQL Server" instead of "MSSQL". It's a lot easier to find in a search that way.

Comment: Why don't you call it "MS SQL Server"? Nowhere, now, can one see it's the microsoft sql server. Not knowing all the product names, it would sound to me like *some* sql server.

Comment: Among other things, the company name is "Microsoft", not "MS". And I've never heard anything referred to as _a_ SQL Server. In fact, in retrospect, it's a fairly dumb name, as it doesn't serve "SQL", but databases.

Comment: Sorry fellas, in our app Db catalog  it's refered to as MS SQL 2000 or MS SQL 2005, hence why I named it the way I did.

Comment: I always laugh on how some ppl get scared of Microsoft on the DB name. All relational DBMS are SQL Servers. Microsoft's one is Microsoft SQL Server, MSSQL in short.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of the linked server so it uses an alternate set of credentials. From SSMS if you right-click on the linked server and go to Properties -> Security, you can change how the authentication is done for the remote server. I don't know if you can specify a Windows-based login for the remote security context, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Tried all that and it didn't work. Tried to use AD_MAIN\DeptGroup as a login and it failed. The only way I can get this to work is by logging into our dev box with our groups functional account, DeptGroup, then creating the linked server using the current login context.